# Neural Network in c++ only outputting 0.5

Tags: c++, neural-network

Im trying to build a NN in C++,

it is being trained on the MNIST handwritten numbers data set to classify a number from a 28*28 black and white image, i have done the same problem in python that worked with a decent success rate but i am trying to do it in c++ for fun, it has 784 inputs (1 for each pixel), 100 hidden and 10 output nodes, it has no biases and a learning rate of 0.3 this is the same as in the python one.

The NN takes in a vector of 784 pixel values normalised from 0.01 to 0.99 in grey scale of an image of a handwritten number and outputs a 10 dimensional vector to identify the image.

However in c++ it always outputs roughly 0.5 for all of the nodes after training. I have tested it with more hidden nodes, different learning rates and more training data but the more training data I trained it on the closer it gets to 0.5. I have also tested that all the functions and overloads work as intended. None of these have helped.

I understand that a CNN would probably work better in this situation but i do not fully understand how to program one.

Here is the training function:

```
void train(std::vector<double> inputs, std::vector<double> targets)
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> inputs2D = {inputs};
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> targets2D = {targets};

        inputs2D = utils::transpose(inputs2D);
        targets2D = utils::transpose(targets2D);

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> hidden_in = utils::dot(ih_weight, inputs2D);
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> hidden_out = utils::activation(hidden_in);

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> final_in = utils::dot(ho_weight, hidden_out);
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> final_out = utils::activation(final_in);

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> output_error = targets2D + (-1* final_out);

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> hidden_error = utils::dot(utils::transpose(ho_weight), output_error);

        ho_weight = (learningRate * utils::dot((output_error * final_out * (1.0 + (-1.0 * final_out))), utils::transpose(hidden_out))) + ho_weight;

        ih_weight = (learningRate * utils::dot((hidden_error * hidden_out * (1.0+(-1.0 * hidden_out))), utils::transpose(inputs2D))) + ih_weight;
    }
```

and here is the full code and training data: [here](https://mega.nz/folder/b8plGAwB#kFB6y5ZaS03AHD58AzBVWg)

it also includes the python file, and the c++ was compiled using c++ 11 with g++

I'm quite new to C++ so feel free to recommend any changes that would make my code better.

Comment: did you use a debugger already? It is not quite clear what your specific question is. I suppose you have a bug in your code, but you didn't provide enough information to enable others to help you. Please read about [mcve], also we would need input, output and expected output (all in the question)

Comment: No i havent tried using a debugger yet. to clarrify the NN takes in a vector of 784 pixel values normalised from 0.01 to 0.99 in grey scale of an image of a handwritten number and outputs a 10 dimensional vector to identify the image, the code compiles properly and runs fine but the outputs always become 10 0.5s after training, the list of inputs are the csv files in the attached file

Comment: never pass vectors as values unless you really know that you need a copy. Use `std::vector<double> &inputs, std::vector<double> &targets` to pass as reference instead, or `const std::vector<double> &inputs, const std::vector<double> &targets` when you don't need to change the values inside the function